# 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to use applymap to my dataset to create floats into integers. But I get the "'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'" error.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import pie, axis, show
from pandas import Series,DataFrame

class Dataset():
def __init__(self, input):
    self.choice = input
    self.file = 0

def read(self):
    if self.choice == ("1"):
        self.file = pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv')
        self.file.plot(kind='bar')
        print(df)

        self.file['Value'].applymap(float)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.file)

def applymap(self):
    return self.file.applymap(float)

i = (input("Pick a DataSet= "))
df = Dataset(i)
df.read()
plt.show()
```

Comment: `self.file['Value']` is a `Series`; you are calling `appplymap` for it while it is a `DataFrame` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As said in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) applymap apply a function to a whole Dataframe not to a series

> Apply a function to a DataFrame that is intended to operate
>   elementwise, i.e. like doing map(func, series) for each series in the
>   DataFrame

To apply for function to a series use [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) or in your case just [astype](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) (np.float) could also work.

If you want to cast the column to float do this :

```
self.file['Value'].astype(np.float32)
```

Comment: I tried with maps. Created a df called 'Fields' that should be added to the first 3 cities. Used df['Fields']=self.file['Reference Area'].map(fields) and its saying TypeError: 'Dataset' object does not support item assignment.

Comment: Please add sample of items in your csv file in order to get good help

Comment: Not a screenshot , edit your answer by adding some data as text